# my dependencies in android studio showing error

Tags: kotlin, dependencies

```
dependencies {

implementation("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0")
implementation("com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4")
implementation("com.android.support:design:28.0.0")
testImplementation("junit:junit:4.+")
androidTestImplementation("com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2")
androidTestImplementation("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2")
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0-alpha02")
```

}
When I added the last line in the dependencies the first and third line says error and it says that
"
Dependencies using groupId com.android.support and androidx.* can not be combined but found com.android.support:design:28.0.0 and androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1 incompatible dependencies"
Please help me I am a beginner...

Answer (score 0):

Android libraries used to be standalone, generally under the `com.android.support` name. The latest effort to organize those dependencies is called Jetpack. Jetpack introduced new code, package name and implementation, referred as Android X.

There are then, "support" (pre-X) and "AndroidX" dependencies. If your project is new, you should be starting with AndroidX out of the box. Otherwise you can migrate to it.

In your case your dependencies `com.android.support:design` and `com.google.android.material` are the same library, in its "support" and "AndroidX" form. Also `com.android.support.test.espresso:..` became `androidx.test.espresso:...`.

Check your project's `gradle.properties for` android.useAndroidX=true` to see if you're on an AndroidX project or not. Then use the proper dependencies.

Check https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings